# spring-jpa Specification implement

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to execute this sql by spring jpa .but I incapable to use Specification  interface to build the specification . can you tell me?

```html
select * from

  (
select distinct user_uid from ua_rel_user_role as userrole0_
 where  ( userrole0_.deleted_at = 0)

      and (userrole0_.role_uid
           in (:role_uid))
      and userrole0_.product_code=:productCode
  ) as r

order by r.user_uid,r. product_code
desc limit 0,10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JPA Named Queries. Follow this [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries).